# Webpack 4 Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)

Tags: webpack

I get this error when i try to run `npm run dev` to compile my scss to css. I know that issue is related to `@import`

**ERROR in ./src/scss/main.scss
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| @import "header";
 @ ./src/index.js 3:0-27**

**src/index.js**
`import "./scss/main.scss";`

**src/scss/main.sccs**

```
@import "header";
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
`
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const WebpackMd5Hash = require('webpack-md5-hash');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
    entry: { main: './src/index.js' },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                include: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'sass')
                ],
                use: ['style-loader', MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin('dist', {}),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: 'style.[contenthash].css',
        }),


  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        inject: false,
        hash: true,
        template: './src/index.html',
        filename: 'index.html'
    }),
    new WebpackMd5Hash()
  ]
  };`
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "post",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "webpack --mode production",
        "dev": "webpack --mode development"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "autoprefixer": "^8.2.0",
        "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
        "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.19",
        "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
        "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.0",
        "node-sass": "^4.8.3",
        "postcss-loader": "^2.1.3",
        "sass-loader": "^6.0.7",
        "style-loader": "^0.20.3",
        "webpack": "^4.4.1",
        "webpack-cli": "^2.0.13",
        "webpack-md5-hash": "0.0.6"
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to generate a standalone .css file? I'm asking because you are using style-loader which would indicate that you are not. But if you are trying to output a .css file, I have had a similar problem and just found a solution.

Comment: @elight what was the solution you came up with?

Comment: Unfortunately, I had spoken too soon. I am off that project at the moment and have so far not found a good solution to the problem.

Answer (score 12):

The issue is within your `module.rule` for handling SASS related files within your project. Within your rule you're only including the SASS files from within your `<path>/src/sass/` directory to be compiled into CSS:

```
{
   test: /\.scss$/,
   include: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'sass')
   ],
   use: ['style-loader', MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader']
}
```

However, a quick scan of your directory structure shows that your `index.js` file is actually importing your `main.scss` file from within the `src/scss/` directory:

**index.js**:

`import "./scss/main.scss";`.

This is a problem because your SASS rule is *only going to compile SASS related files to CSS from within the `src/sass` directory*, but your SASS related files are actually located within your `src/scss` directory.

**Therefore, your SASS files are never actually compiled to CSS appropriately.**

To resolve this either remove the `include` part all together or change the include location to the correct path location of your SASS files:

`include: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'scss')
],`

Another thing I would consider doing is adding the `.scss` extension to your imports within your `main.scss` file:

`@import "header.scss";`

or alternatively adding a resolve section within your `webpack.config.js` file so you can simplify your imports and still have webpack handle them appropriately. Something along the lines of:

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.scss']
}
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Golden! you saved me hours of my time!! Much appreciated!!

Comment: np glad it was helpful

Answer (score 8):

To solve this problem for `Webpack 4`, first install `sass-loader`, `node-sass`, `style-loader`, and `css-loader` via `npm`:

```
npm install sass-loader node-sass style-loader css-loader --save-dev
```

Then add this rules to the `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      // ...Other rules,
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
          'style-loader',
          // Translates CSS into CommonJS
          'css-loader',
          // Compiles Sass to CSS
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

**Note:** The order is important, e.g: Don't put `css-loader` before `style-loader` or you'll probably get weird erros!

Comment: module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2?)$/,
          use: {
            loader: "file-loader",
          },
        },
        // CSS rules
        {
          test: /\\.css$/,
          use: [

Answer (score 0):

I fixed these similar issue by following [these link](https://github.com/storybooks/storybook/issues/1603#issuecomment-320508394).

I updated `rule` section of `webpack.config.js` as follows

```
rules: [
    {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use : [
                {
                        loader: 'style-loader',
                },
                {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                                sourceMap: true,
                        }
                }
            ]
    }
]
```

Then installed the dependencies as follows.

using yarn

```
yarn add style-loader --dev
yarn add css-loader --dev
```

using npm

```
npm install style-loader --save-dev
npm install css-loader --save-dev
```

Comment: It's working.  module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2?)$/,
          use: {
            loader: "file-loader",
          },
        },
        // CSS rules
        {
          test: /\\.css$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'style-loader',
            },
            {
              loader: 'css-loader',
              options: {
                sourceMap: true,
              }
            }
          ],
        },
      ],

Answer (score 0):

Just add these lines to the webpack.config.js under rule :

```
{
  test: /\.css$/i,                                                                                                                                                             
  use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],                                                                                                                          
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I had `import 'tailwindcss/tailwind.css'` in one of my Typescript files, removing it fixed it for me