# Webpack 4 - Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@'

Tags: javascript, webpack

I recently upgraded from Webpack 3 to 4. It's now throwing an error:

> Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' You may need an
>   appropriate loader to handle this file type. | @import
>   './scss/variables.scss'; |  | * {  @ ./src/index.js 1:0-22

In my styles.scss file, I am doing the following:

```
@import 'scss/variables.scss';

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

In my index.js file, I am only doing the following:

```
import './style.scss';
```

In my webpack.dev.js, all I changed was an addition of mode: 'development':

```
const StyleLintPlugin = require('stylelint-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'public/bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: ['babel-loader', 'eslint-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['css-loader', 'sass-loader'])
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new StyleLintPlugin({
            configFile: '.stylelintrc',
            context: 'src',
            files: '**/*.scss',
            failOnError: false,
            quiet: false,
            syntax: 'scss'
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin('public/style.css'),
        new Dotenv()
    ]
};
```

I don't know what change from Webpack 3 to 4 has caused this error.

The issue I'm having is very similar to the issue posted here: [Webpack 4 Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50477167/)

I have been through all related stackoverflow questions and none of them helped.

Here are the relevant dependencies in my package.json:

```
"babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
"css-loader": "^0.28.11",
"eslint-loader": "^1.9.0",
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
"node-sass": "^4.9.0",
"sass-loader": "^6.0.7",
"style-loader": "^0.20.3",
"stylelint-webpack-plugin": "^0.10.5",
"uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.5",
"webpack": "^4.8.3",
"webpack-cli": "^2.1.4"
```

Here are the relevant  scripts in my package.json file, for reference in the comments:

```
"scripts": {
    "watch": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack --mode development --watch --progress",
    "build": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack --mode production"
},
```

Comment: Maybe of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47300984/unexpected-character-you-may-need-an-appropriate-loader-to-handle-this-file

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I've already been through all related stackoverflow questions and none of them helped me :(.

Comment: I would suggest trying just the loaders `style-loader`, `css-loader`, `sass-loader` first to find out if the problem is with ExtractTextPlugin.

Comment: Did you upgrade sass loader to latest version?

Comment: Hi @sdgluck I just tried that and unfortunately I'm still getting the same problem, thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: Hi @StefanoVuerich I have. I did npm update to update all the packages in my project. I'll add the package.json to the question.

Comment: Try also delete node-modules folder and npm install again ;) latest version of sass-loader  if 7.0.1

Comment: @Edward did you try with the alpha version of Extract plugin? Seems that the stable version does not work yet with webpack 4 https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/701. You can install the beta with `npm i -D extract-text-webpack-plugin@next`

Comment: @StefanoVuerich I deleted the node_modules and did npm install again, and now it's not even running. I'll have to fix this before testing your fix Raul Rene.

Comment: What is not even running? If you could not npm install there is something wrong somewhere else...Anyway I can also confirm Raul's opinion

Comment: I've got it running now, just attempting Raul's fix.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem was the script I was using to run Webpack did not specify the config file. This is what it should look like:

```
"scripts": {
  "watch": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack --watch --config webpack.dev.js",
},
```

I believe this was generating the @import problem because it was not loading the css-loader as without specifying the config file like above, it uses a default Webpack development config which does not include the css-loader.

Answer (score 4):

As I mentioned in a comment on your question there's an open issue with Webpack 4 compatibility: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/701

A fix for now is to install the alpha version of the library. I've done a small setup just now to test this and it works with webpack 4.

Install the alpha version `npm i -D extract-text-webpack-plugin@next --save`. Then install `css-loader`, `sass-loader` and `node-sass`.

Then in the webpack config file:

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

...

module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            },
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['css-loader', 'sass-loader'])
        }
    ]
},

plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('bundle.css'),
]
```

This correctly worked for me, and also concatenated multiple scss files that were using `@import` statements.

In package.json it should look like

```
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
"webpack": "^4.8.3"
```

**Edit:** Just as a side note, apparently [mini-css-extract-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin) works fine with webpack 4.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me either. I tried downgrading webpack to 4.8.3 as well copying everything you've done yet it still produces the same issue.

Comment: What's the version of webpack-cli you're using? Also, how are you running the bundle? Have you tried using `rules` instead of `loaders` and removing other plugins?

Comment: "webpack-cli": "^2.1.4" - I am using rules instead of loaders now.

Comment: Strange. I have `webpack-cli: 2.1.3`. I've just tried running with `-p` for production and still works. How are you running the bundle? If it's directly from the cmd line it might be something related to the globally installed npm versions. Try to use a script from package json

Comment: I have updated my question to include the scripts I am using. I am running  `npm run watch`.

Comment: Can you try to just use something like `"watch": "webpack -d -w --progress"` instead of pointing directly to the node_modules? If that doesn't work, create a script that just prints the version `"bla": "webpack -v"` and check if prints the correct version

Comment: It's producing the same issue when I run `webpack -d -w --progress`, and the `webpack -v` displays the correct version, 4.8.3.

Comment: Sorry mate I don't have any other ideas. Check again for the correct extract plugin version in node_modules, make sure you have the alpha installed. 
Try to setup a small demo with nothing more than an index file, webpack and 2 scss files and see if that works. Then figure out one by one what's breaking. My minimal example is working fine. You could always try the mini-css-extract plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll give that a go.

Answer (score 1):

**This worked for me**: Replace your webpack styling config to the below code

```
 module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.(css|sass|scss)$/,
            use: [
              {
                loader: 'style-loader'
              },
              {
                loader: 'css-loader'
              },
              {
                loader: 'sass-loader'
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
```

I hope this resolves your issue thanks