# Unexpected character '@' (1:0) @tailwind base when run Docker

Tags: docker, next.js, dockerfile, tailwind-css

I am deploying my nextJs project using tailwind build Docker, my package.json:
(And another dependencies)

```
{
    "name": "frontend",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "proxy": "http://localhost:3003",
    "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1"
    }
}
```

My css file has error:

```
@tailwind base;           //<------------------ error
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

.border-b-sm {
  border-bottom-width: 0.0625rem;
}
.border-b-neutral-border-weak {
  border-bottom-color: var(--color-neutral-border-weak);
}
```

And my DockerFile:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/frontend

ARG PORT=3000

ENV PORT ${PORT}

ENV NODE_ENV=production

EXPOSE ${PORT}

COPY package.json . 


RUN npm install

RUN npm install next

COPY . .

CMD ["npm","run","dev"]
```

When I run on my computer, there is no problem. But when run in docker container:

```
./src/app/globals.css
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
> @tailwind base;
| @tailwind components;
| @tailwind utilities;
```

Comment: checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50622971/webpack-4-module-parse-failed-unexpected-character?

Comment: @AmalPs I am running in local as well, but in docker, this error appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a minimal setup.

Packages in `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "next-tailwind",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "13.5.5",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.17",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.1.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.33",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}
```

Contents of `tailwind.config.js`:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  purge: ['./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
  darkMode: false,
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Contents of `styles/globals.css`:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Minimal page content in `app/page.tsx`:

```
import Image from "next/image";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="flex justify-center items-center h-screen">
      <h1 className="text-4xl font-bold">
        Hello, Next.js with Tailwind!
      </h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Now the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Build.

```bash
docker build -t next-tailwind .
```

Run.

```bash
docker run --rm -p 3000:3000 next-tailwind
```

Go to http://127.0.0.1:3000/.

You can find more details of a simple working setup [here](https://datawookie.dev/blog/2024/01/next-tailwind-docker/).

Comment: YEAH, my bad is cmd docker with `npm run dev` instead of `npm start`. Thankyou so much.

Comment: I should build the tailwind first too.